# Can I Use Async to Perform Fire-and-Forget NHibernate Saves in an ASP.NET MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asynchronous, c#-5.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses NHibernate to persist data into a SQL Server database.

There are cases where I want to save an entry into a database (initially triggered by a call into an action method on a controller) but there's no need to block the caller.

Is it "safe" to try to implement a fire-and-forget mechanism into the database that will put the database call into a Task and then invoke it on the background so control can return immediately to the caller?  (OR accomplish the same thing with BackgroundWorker or the "async/await" keywords)  I need a solution where NHibernate will not get tripped up by ASP.NET trying to clean up its ISession, which is per-request.  I'm using Autofac for lifetime management on the session.  I assume that the database operation would have a slightly longer lifetime than the web request itself, and I'm not sure how smoothly that would work.

Comment: Maybe you should put your data to queue (MSMQ) first and from there pickup and perform save to db? Everything can work in transaction and have transactional retry mechanism for free. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not safe to do this; I have a [blog post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html). The problem is that when you have no requests in progress, it is possible that your entire AppDomain can be torn down. Also, consider what would happen if the database insert failed for some reason? If you return early, then there's no way to notify the client of an error.

A reliable solution must store the data in some kind of persistent place before returning success to the caller. This can be directly in the database, or in a queue of some kind (to be later processed by an independent worker).

Comment: Thanks, Stephen!  In my use case, sporadic data loss is acceptable (as long as it's related only to the odd AppDomain restart and not just weird ongoing bugginess).  Understandably this wouldn't be appropriate for storing customer orders or other such crucial transactions!  Thanks again!